# Click Once App Not Starting From Start Menu

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a winforms application installed using ClickOnce.

It instals and opens correctly.

Then subsequent attempts to open ClickOnce app from the Start Menu fail.

However I can start the application from the application.exe file in the C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\JAX2EPR8.HG9\2D914NHW.VZQ\cmsc..tion_1c466b55ca1d742f_0001.0000_ba5046e2bd838a79 folder.

In the short term I can put a shortcut on the desktop to the .exe file but this is not a practical solution long term.

We get this error message....

/////////////////////////////////////

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows                                             : 10.0.19045.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime        : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll                  : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
clr.dll                                     : 4.8.4645.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
dfdll.dll                                 : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
dfshim.dll                                            : 10.0.19041.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
Deployment url                                 : file:///C:/Users/Nicole/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Internet%20Explorer/Quick%20Launch/User%20Pinned/TaskBar/CMS%20Console%20Dot%20Net%204.5.appref-ms%7C

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\Nicole\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\CMS Console Dot Net 4.5.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Downloading file:///F:/CMS Console 4.5/CMS Console Dot Net 4.5.application did not succeed.
+ The device is not ready.

```
                            + The device is not ready.

                            + The device is not ready.
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [17/08/2023 13:44:19] : Activation of C:\Users\Nicole\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\CMS Console Dot Net 4.5.appref-ms| has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [17/08/2023 13:44:19] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
- Downloading file:///F:/CMS Console 4.5/CMS Console Dot Net 4.5.application did not succeed.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifest(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.Net.WebException
- The device is not ready.

```
                            - Source: System
                            - Stack trace:
                                            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                                            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                            --- Inner Exception ---
                            System.Net.WebException
                            - The device is not ready.

                            - Source: System
                            - Stack trace:
                                            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
                                            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
                            --- Inner Exception ---
                            System.IO.IOException
                            - The device is not ready.

                            - Source: mscorlib
                            - Stack trace:
                                            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                                            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
                                            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
                                            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
                                            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.

/////////////////////////////////////////////

The WinForms application has been in use for about 10 years with incremental updates without this issue occurring.

This started happening about a week ago.

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks in advance.

Will

Comment: Error message: `Downloading file:///F:/CMS Console 4.5/CMS Console Dot Net 4.5.application did not succeed. + The device is not ready.` Is the F:\ drive accessible at launch?

Comment: No, the F:\ drive only exists when the USB stick is inserted.

But I don't understand why it is trying to access the F drive. The application was already installed previously!

Comment: I've no idea why it's hitting the F: drive. Does it do it when you manually make a short cut to the .exe?

Comment: No, creating a shortcut to the exe is our current work around.

I was wondering if it was due to recent Dot Net Framework or Windows updates?

I think what I will do is take an immediate snapshot of the the folder contents after doing an install and then seeing if any files get removed by the anti virus software later.